# Write a program that sells popcorn and drinks using the enumeration type c++ class

Tags: c++

Here is my task: Write a program that sells popcorn and drinks using the enumeration type. You must use the following within your
program:
enum sizes {SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, JUMBO};
sizes popcornSize, drinkSize;
You should create a menu that asks the user to choose what size of drink they want and to choose what size of
popcorn they want. Then you should print out the total cost of the drink and popcorn.

Prices:
Popcorn Small= 1.25, medium=2.25, large=3.50, jumbo=4.25
Soda Small=1.50, medium=2.50, large=3.75, jumbo=4.50

Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    enum sizes { SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, JUMBO };
    sizes popcornSize, drinkSize;

    double sp=1.25, mp=2.25, lp=3.50, jp=4.25, TOTALp, TOTALs, ss=1.50,         ms=2.50, ls=3.75, js=4.50 ;
    char choice, answer, Psize, Ssize;
    int how_many;
    cout << "Hello I am selling popcorn and sodas, would you like to buy  some? type yes or no please." << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice == 'yes')
    {
        cout << "Great, what would you like popcorn or soda? Type P for popcorn and S for soda." << endl;
        cin >> answer;
        if (answer = 'P')
        {
            cout << "what size popcorn would you like (type s for small, m for medium, l for large or j for jumbo) and how many (type a single number)?" << endl;
            cin >> Psize >> how_many;
            if (Psize = 's')
            {
                TOTALp = sp*how_many;
                cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALp << endl;
            }
            else if (Psize = 'm')
            {
                TOTALp = mp*how_many;
                cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALp << endl;
            }
            else if (Psize = 'l')
            {
                TOTALp = lp*how_many;
                cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALp << endl;
            }
            else if (Psize = 'j')
            {
                TOTALp = jp*how_many;
                cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALp << endl;
            }


            else if (answer = 'S')
            {

                cout << "what size soda would you like (type small, medium, large or jumbo) and how many (type a single number)?" << endl;
                cin >> Ssize >> how_many;
                if (Ssize = 's')
                {
                    TOTALs = ss*how_many;
                    cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALs << endl;
                }
                else if (Ssize = 'm')
                {
                    TOTALs = ms*how_many;
                    cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALs << endl;
                }
                else if (Ssize = 'l')
                {
                    TOTALs = ls*how_many;
                    cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALs << endl;
                }
                else if (Ssize = 'j')
                {
                    TOTALs = js*how_many;
                    cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALs << endl;
                }

            }
            cout << "Thanks for buying come again soon." << endl;
        }

        }
        else if (choice == 'no')
            cout << "Okay have a great day!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I need help implementing enumeration into the program and how I'd make all  of these if/else statements into a switch structure. Also, for some reason when I run my program after the user enters their choice the program ends and I cant figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

Your program ends, because choice is never 'yes' nor 'no'. As choice is a char it just can be a single character. Change 'yes' to 'y' and 'no' to 'n' and it should work.

I give you an example of how to write a switch statement so you can adapt it for the rest of your code.

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "iostream"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    enum sizes { SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE, JUMBO };
    sizes popcornSize, drinkSize;

    double sp=1.25, mp=2.25, lp=3.50, jp=4.25, TOTALp, TOTALs, ss=1.50,         ms=2.50, ls=3.75, js=4.50 ;
    char choice, answer, Psize, Ssize;
    int how_many;
    cout << "Hello I am selling popcorn and sodas, would you like to buy  some? type yes or no please." << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 'y':
        cout << "Great, what would you like popcorn or soda? Type P for popcorn and S for soda." << endl;
        cin >> answer;
        if (answer = 'P')
        {
            cout << "what size popcorn would you like (type s for small, m for medium, l for large or j for jumbo) and how many (type a single number)?" << endl;
            cin >> Psize >> how_many;
            if (Psize = 's')
            {
                TOTALp = sp*how_many;
                cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALp << endl;
            }
            else if (Psize = 'm')
            {
                TOTALp = mp*how_many;
                cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALp << endl;
            }
            else if (Psize = 'l')
            {
                TOTALp = lp*how_many;
                cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALp << endl;
            }
            else if (Psize = 'j')
            {
                TOTALp = jp*how_many;
                cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALp << endl;
            }


            else if (answer = 'S')
            {

                cout << "what size soda would you like (type small, medium, large or jumbo) and how many (type a single number)?" << endl;
                cin >> Ssize >> how_many;
                if (Ssize = 's')
                {
                    TOTALs = ss*how_many;
                    cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALs << endl;
                }
                else if (Ssize = 'm')
                {
                    TOTALs = ms*how_many;
                    cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALs << endl;
                }
                else if (Ssize = 'l')
                {
                    TOTALs = ls*how_many;
                    cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALs << endl;
                }
                else if (Ssize = 'j')
                {
                    TOTALs = js*how_many;
                    cout << "Okay you total is: " << TOTALs << endl;
                }

            }
            cout << "Thanks for buying come again soon." << endl;
        }
    break;
    case 'n':
        cout << "Okay have a great day!" << endl;
    break;
    default:
        cout << "I dont understand...!" << endl;
    break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! However, I am still stuck on how I am to implement the enumeration data into my code, in regards to the sizes and prices of popcorn and soda

Comment: The question is, what do you want the user to enter? You could write a switch case statement that takes the user input and sets the enum values in each case for example.